# Task queue system with minimum-worker pool

Tags: scheduling

Looking for a small-scale (<1000 concurrent jobs) scheduling server to satisfy these requirements:

- **Server maintains a minimum number of worker nodes** (e.g., always keep 10 workers alive; implies a keepalive check for workers)
- **Workers run in user-space** (no sudo/root access available)
- Worker nodes are launched via a specified shell command (behaves like SSH)
- Gratis

Other things to note:

- Communication between server and workers can be over sockets or over file-system (all systems are over NFS)
- Can even be a module for Python/Perl/Go (since these are available on worker systems)

It takes multiple minutes for a worker node to spin up, so I'd like to always keep a certain number of worker nodes online to handle incoming tasks.

I am able to compile server and worker binaries (or modules) on an architecturally similar system and copy over to target systems if needed.

A GUI is *not required*; in fact, I'd prefer a purely commandline tool.

So far, I've looked at Zookeeper, Jenkins, Kala, Chronos, but they either require root on worker nodes, or do not have the concept of keeping a minimum number of workers alive.

Given that there are dozens (hundreds?) of scheduling systems, I'm reasonably sure such a system exists, but I'm lacking the right terminology to find it.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HashiCorp Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io/) fits every one of the requirements mentioned above:

- Tasks can run multiple instances, with built in retry
- Server and Client can run in userspace (no sudo/root access necessary)
- Client can be launched via a shell command
- Communication is over sockets
- No module needed, since API is over HTTP REST
- Gratis
- [Open source](https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad) (bonus)